# VBA - Colar Relatórios na Sheet determinada

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Estou montando um macro que abre um relatório específico cópia os dados e cola em uma outra planilha em determinada *sheet*. Porém estou com dificuldades na parte para colar na outra planilha.

Até o momento temos:

```
Dim as Integer
Data= Sheets("nome da sheet").Range("A1")
Range("A1").Value = Data

Workbooks.Open Filename: =
"Caminho do relatório\nome do relatório" & Data & ".xlsm"

Range("A2","R16").Copy

Active.Sheet("nome da sheet")

Range(A5,R65).pastespecial
```

E aparece a mensagem de erro **424**;

Agora entra o problema. Não consigo colar esse relatório na planilha (aliás essa planilha é onde estou montando a macro)

Comment: Tente fazer tudo o que quer gravando uma macro e depois estudo o código. Creio que sua pergunta está muito abrangente...

Answer (score 1):

Natalia,
Tente mudar essa parte:

```
Range("A2","R16").Copy

Active.Sheet("nome da sheet") Range(A5,R65).pastespecial
```

Por:

```
Range("A2:R16").Copy

Sheets("nome da sheet").Range("A5").Paste
```